# Does hard-disk space influence the execution of a program?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I have a program that is running and it produces log material to write to the disk, but my hard disk space is 100% used so, logs are not getting produced. Does this kind of scenario affects the execution progress of program ?

Comment: If the program *can't* utilize the file-system disk *because* it is full (this also may preclude the ability to use [more] virtual memory) then *yes, it can and does* influence the program .. but the symptoms *already* indicated the answer to this question.

Comment: yes, it does, especially if program operation involves accessing the hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty vague question, because it depends on an application, but generally yes, it does.